# Inherited Angular/Compass site - How was the JS minified?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby, compression, minify

I received an existing site to make a small change to the data model, but I understand how to recompress the JS. Sadly, no real readme.txt was provided.

There are no configurations I can see declaring dependency paths for JS libraries - yet, the scripts are successfully minified with their required deps. There is no gulp or grunt file present, only a config.rb, and Gemfile, and Gemfile.lock.

```
    GEM
      remote: https://rubygems.org/
      specs:
        chunky_png (1.3.3)
        compass (1.0.1)
          chunky_png (~> 1.2)
          compass-core (~> 1.0.1)
          compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
          rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
          rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
          sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
        compass-core (1.0.1)
          multi_json (~> 1.0)
          sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
        compass-import-once (1.0.5)
          sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
        ffi (1.9.6)
        multi_json (1.10.1)
        rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
        rb-inotify (0.9.5)
          ffi (>= 0.5.0)
        sass (3.4.9)

    PLATFORMS
      ruby

    DEPENDENCIES
      compass (~> 1.0)
      sass (~> 3.4.0)
```

Compass runs fine, the CSS is compiled/compressed.

Any idea of what I'm missing here? I know this is vague and might simply indicate that I do not have a crucial configuration document.

Comment: I rarely use Ruby, but I would start by `grep`-ing for the names of dependencies, to see if they are listed somewhere.

Comment: Yah - I can't find them mentioned anywhere except for within their own directories. Basically, I've done all the initial troubleshooting one could do in looking blindly - just wondering if perhaps I am missing a fundamental concept.

Answer (score 0):

99.9% certain that the original developer didn't include the build system files - and I'll have to rebuild. NBD.